# How do I ground my chassis?

Tags: power, grounding

I'm working on a project with 90 solenoids mounted on a metal plate (see A below). Each solenoid could draw 2 Amps, however I will only be using 20 at max at a time.

I can switch between using a wired (to socket) power supply (B) and a battery (D) if a socket is not available.

(C) Is earth. Which won't be used when using battery.

My question: Do I need to ground the metal plate? If so, do I need to connect it to point C or B/D.

Note: B and D are connected.

I would connect it to point B/D, but I am afraid that the high currents might mess with this.

[image: psu battery and solenoids]

Comment: Metal plates are usually earthed for safety - grounding means nothing particularly in most countries except another name for the 0 volt reference in a schematic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have potentially lethal voltage (you do) and the equipment is not [double insulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II) you must ground any exposed metalwork. This protective ground should be to the earth connection of the incoming mains.

Comment: So, If I understand corretly, I should connect it to earth (C) and can't/shouldn't  use the battery? or can I just wire C, B and D and A together? I want to use the battery.

Comment: There is no reason not to use the battery. However you DO need to think out your earthing. What is the battery referenced to? what is the earth reference for your system? It sounds as it you haven't really answered this question, but you need to.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an electrical engineer. What to you mean by: the battery referenced to? The minus of the supply unit is connected to minus of the battery. Both their plus sides are connected to a switch, so I can choose which supply has closed circuit. And the earth reference is earth wire (the green yellow wire) which is only connected if I use the outlet.

Comment: To be honest, if you are not an electrical engineer, and you don't understand that statement, you shouldn't be doing this. Constructing a piece of mains powered equipment is no joke, and getting the earthing right is only a small (although important) part of the job.  This is not the place for Electricity 101.

Comment: I am a mechatronics engineer. I know I need to think out my earthing, but I couldn't find an answer to my question. Both the power supply and battery are 12 VDC. If  I understand your answer correctly, I should just wire the metal to the earth wire coming from the outlet. But then the metal wouldn't be earthed whenever I am using the battery. The metal and everything is enclosed in a wooden frame and doesn't form a direct hazard. If I use the battery I should just have it closed at all times?

Comment: @aWiseMan yes, closed all the time and that still insufficient. It must be double insulated. Simplest way to do this is to have two separate, nested cases with two independent opening mechanisms, but any solution that will keep your device insulated in case of any one failure (like a break in case element) will do.

Comment: "potentially lethal voltage" for these purposes are 30VAC/42VDC and higher. So with a 12V battery you don't have any worries UNLESS there is some form of voltage booster in the equipment that gets you above those levels. However I strongly recommend that you AT LEAST get your design reviewed by someone with appropriate experience and qualifications, to avoid the possibility of future disappointment or worse.

Comment: why would you go to the hassle of double insulating the case? just put a big solid safety ground on there, and make sure that there is a suitable breaker upstream. Job done.

Comment: @danmcb solenoid *is* a kind of voltage booster. And solid ground is difficult when battery operated.

Comment: @Mołot how is a solenoid a booster? because of back EMF's?

Answer (score 2):

> My question: Do I need to ground the metal plate?

IEC 60950 UL 60950 are the norms that drive my answer.

---

If the 2 following conditions are met simultaneously, than you are not required to tie to Earth anything. People can touch your system with bare hands.

1. Your system is powered by a commercial power supply or a commercial battery and your power supply voltage is smaller than "60 VDC" and "42 Vpk AC"
2. Your system doesn't develop internally voltages greater than "60 VDC" and "42 Vpk AC"

Example:

Your system requires a power supply of 12 VDC, sinks a current of 2 A, and develop voltages across any 2 wires or any wire with respect to EARTH greater than "60 VDC" or "42 Vpk AC"

Your system is not electrically safe and is not UL60950 compliant.

In this case you have to enclose your system in an "Electrical enclosure" compliant to norm UL60950.

Comment: Both the battery and the commercial power supply are 12 VDC. How do you know it develops more than 60VDC?

Comment: In your circuits you got coils that, if driven by a square wave signal, may develop votages higher  than 12 VDC. Inspect your circuit by scope.

Comment: If the power supply is isolated isn't the voltage as referenced to earth an arbitrary value?

Comment: The UL safety engineer by a scope inspects selected couples of nodes. If he/she finds a voltage greater than 60 VDC or 42 Vpk then your system has hazardous voltages and you have to isolate it from the touch of a person reading UL60950.

Comment: @aWiseMan *"How do you know it develops more than 60VDC?"* - if you can't test it and your system contains any elements that can generate higher voltages (like coils or anything similar to Villard cascade) then you simply must assume that circuit can generate such voltages and act as if it does.

Comment: If you can't test it and you can't UL certify your product than I don't know what to say. Post here the schematics.